# Understanding lag plot ,ACF plot and auto-correlation plots

Tags: plotting, arima

I have a data-frame of **2809 rows**  which is an unevenly spaced time-series

```
    date        adate

0   2012-03-30  0.0
1   2012-03-30  1.0
2   2012-03-31  19.0
3   2012-04-19  1.0
4   2012-04-20  1.0
```

which I interpolated linearly so that i could fit an ARIMA on it

```
df_rs = t111.set_index('date').resample('D').mean().interpolate('linear').round(1) #resample according to Days and linear inetrpolate and round values
```

Following are the **ACF, auto-correlation and lag plots** of now evenly spaced the data.
I need to understand what properties and parameters can be safely inferenced/understood about my data from these plots.
[image: autocorrelation] 
[image: ACF and lag]

Notice I've made some comments in the pictures as well,are they apropiate?
I a real noob at this, any and all insights are welcome. ELI5? Thanks a bunch :D
[image: autocorr]